# Discord.js User DM from id

Tags: discord, discord.js, userid, dm

Im trying to dm a user but I only have there id. This is the code im using:

```js
const member = bot.users.cache.find(ID)
member.send('TEXT')
```

it isn't working. Does anyone know why?

Comment: "it isn't working" isn't enough for us to diagnose a problem. What's happening? Are you getting an errors?

Comment: i get this error i get this TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at module.exports (/Users/thomasmcdonald/Documents/Froggit/tickets/createTicket.js:7:52)

Comment: Either ID is not a valid snowflake or the user isn't cached.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is not cached you can do this.

```
const member = bot.users.fetch('user-id',false,true)
```

That helps to fetch member data directly from API. more at [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=fetch)

Answer (score 0):

Like somebody else has stated, the user probably isn't cached. There isn't anything you can do about this as far as I can tell.

If you want to avoid the `undefined` error your having, and to catch any errors that may occur when sending the message:

```
const member = bot.users.cache.find(ID);

if (member) member.send('TEXT').catch(console.error);
```